# Binary tree validation

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Been working through some of Hacker Ranks Cracking the Coding Interview problems and just recently got to this one: [Binary Tree Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-is-binary-search-tree/problem).

In the problem description, the author goes over what is considered to be a valid binary tree.

> "The  value of every node in a node's left subtree is less than the
>   data value of that node."

However they mention that this tree

[image]

is valid. But by their description of a valid binary search tree, wouldn't this tree be invalid because Node 4 has a left child of Node 5, which is greater. Or am I misunderstanding what makes a valid BST?

Comment: You're correct. This isn't a valid binary search tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: But by their description of a valid binary search tree, wouldn't this tree be invalid because Node 4 has a left child of Node 5, which is greater. Or am I misunderstanding what makes a valid BST?

A: You're correct. The image and the line they state are contradicting each other in this case.

The author has clearly stated the following definition for a valid BST:

> For the purposes of this challenge, we define a binary search tree to
>   be a binary tree with the following properties:
>
> 1. The data value of every node in a node's left subtree is less than the
>      data value of that node.
> 2. The data value of every node in a node's right subtree is greater than
>      the data value of that node.
> 3. The data value of every node is distinct.

Hence, the tree in the image doesn't qualify as a valid BST.